# Отправка сообщения whatsapp php

Tags: php, whatsapp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочий способ отправить сообщение в whatsapp при помощи php
не могу найти

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=whatsapp+php - берите любой репозиторий и вперед

Comment: Напишите, если найдете рабочий. Вацап постоянно "банит" старые способы

Comment: а как тогда yowsup для python работает?

Comment: сейчас также работает? оба раза что я пробовал, не работал

Comment: Ну смотри Сам я писал бота на питоне на основе этой статьи: https://chat-api.com/ru/whatsapp-bot-python.html, но у них есть подоьбное на PHP, например: https://chat-api.com/ru/whatsapp-bot-php.html, но я не проверял. Если будет нужна помощь по написанию бота, то напиши мне, вместе справимся)